# Testcafe test fails because "Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource" with VPN, but without VPN it works

Tags: testing, dns, vpn, e2e-testing, testcafe

The test fails when I'm connected through the VPN but without it works fine. It performs a click to this URL:
[https://www.google.com/search?q=let+me+google+that+for+you](https://www.google.com/search?q=let%20me%20google%20that%20for%20you)

I tried with the `--proxy-bypass` setting but I suppose I'm not doing it right, any guidance on how it should look like?

Comment: Are you using a runner class?

Comment: Nope, CLI command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A VPN should not affect your tests. Judging by the symptoms, it looks like you are using a proxy, not a VPN. If it's true, the proxy server address should be specified using the `--proxy` option as described [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--proxy-host) mentioned below.

```
--proxy <host>
```

Specifies the proxy server used in your local network to access the Internet.

```
testcafe chrome my-tests/**/*.js --proxy proxy.corp.mycompany.com
testcafe chrome my-tests/**/*.js --proxy 172.0.10.10:8080
```

You can also specify authentication credentials with the proxy host.

```
testcafe chrome my-tests/**/*.js --proxy username:password@proxy.mycorp.com
```

As for the `--proxy-bypass` option, it has the opposite meaning. You can use it to specify resources that are not proxied, for example, the ones that are hosted inside of your local network.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I made it work exactly with what you said! proxy option and then the bypass for the ones hosted inside my local network!